# avg columns and order them in sql

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, average

I need to order this avg values desc, but somehow I can't. Help please

[image: my query is something like this:]

The solution is probably very simple:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to order the columns having the highest value in left column. I also assume that you are using SQL Server. It certainly looks like that from the pictures.

```
The solution is probably very simple.
```

Don't know about that. You tell me...

```
with C(A, B, C) as
(
  -- Your query goes here
)
select [1],[2],[3]
from (
       select Val, row_number() over(order by Val desc) as rn
       from C unpivot (Val for Col in(A, B, C)) U
     ) T
pivot (min(val) for rn in ([1],[2],[3])) P
```

[Proof of concept](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/72051)

Comment: sorry, I'm afraid I don't fully understand this query. Where would I put the field names I'd like to query and sort?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT X FROM
(
    SELECT aa X FROM table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT bb X FROM table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cc X FROM table
) a
ORDER BY X DESC
```

Will something like that do it?

Comment: I think you mean `SELECT X` and `ORDER BY X`